# Cannot find namespace 'SpotifyApi' (@types/spotify-api) error in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, import, node-modules

I have two projects, one api and one client (angular) project. In my angular project I have the following `tsconfig.json`:

```ts
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
    "paths": {                          /* <-- note this bit */
      "@shared/*": ["../api/src/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

As you can see I added the `paths` object in order to import files from `"../api/src/*"` (the api project). This is working fine, only I have a file at `"../api/src/schema/request.d.ts"`:

```ts
export namespace Request {
  export interface GetPlaylistTracks {
    Params: {
      playlistId: string;
    };
    ResBody: SpotifyApi.PagingObject<any> | undefined;
    ReqBody: {};
    ReqQuery: {
      offset: string;
      limit: string;
    };
  }
}
```

which I'm trying to import inside the angular project like so

```ts
import { Request } from '@shared/schema/request';
```

getting the error

```
Error: ../api/src/schema/request.d.ts:26:14 - error TS2833: Cannot find namespace 'SpotifyApi'. Did you mean 'Spotify'?

26     ResBody: SpotifyApi.PagingObject<any> | undefined;
```

The namespace `SpotifyApi` is coming from `@types/spotify-api` (which is working fine inside my api project). In both projects inside my `package.json` I have

```ts
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/spotify-api": "^0.0.22"
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of having on devDependencies Did you try adding "@types/spotify-api": "^0.0.22" to dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by adding

```ts
import 'spotify-api';
```

to `request.d.ts` file. Still I don't know why this is necessary. Btw., I'm having the same problem when not using `paths` property, i.e. `SpotifyApi` is not working inside any angular project, only in my backend project. VS Code is not showing any errors, they just appear in the terminal/web client.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having on devDependencies Did you try adding "@types/spotify-api": "^0.0.22" to dependencies.

- "dependencies": Packages required by your application in production.
- "devDependencies": Packages that are only needed for local
  development and testing.

Since you are referring the SpotifyApi.PagingObjec in a model. You need yo add it to dependencies.

Comment: Yes I tried this, it makes no difference...